# why we use "to be" and "to be + past participle"?

Tags: meaning

1. The children were to be driven.
2. Nicholas was not to be of the party.

I could not understand what are the meanings of these sentences? why these sentences have been used "to be driven" and "to be" in two sentences respectively.

Please help me to understand this. Sometimes I feel like this is like a passive voice, but I have a clue.

Comment: Yes, they are passive. 'Someone' was going to drive the children (convey them somewhere in a vehicle, presumably). The person organising the trip was not including Nicholas in the group.

Comment: The first is passive: the children were to be driven (by someone). The second is odd. I don't understand what "not to be of the party" means.

Comment: Only active/action verbs can be passive. 2) is not passive.

Answer (score 1):

1. The children were to be driven.
2. Nicholas was not to be of the party.

The first sentence is passive, of course.  Its form describes *the future from the viewpoint of the past*. These structures can refer to a past action, intention, or plan when its realization or intended realization still lies in the future.

Consider:

Mr. Klein **was to be** our representative at the meeting, but it was canceled.

The dean **was about to arrive** when a terrible argument broke out at the meeting.

She **was to become** a prima ballerina.

Cynthia knew she **was to be fired**, but the method still came as a surprise.  (passive)

Cynthia knew that *her boss would fire her*, but the method still came as a surprise. (active)

There **was to be** a meeting that day, but it never happened.

The second sentence is active and negative.

Consider:

Nicholas **was not to be** part of our group.
*Something that did not happen. Seen from the viewpoint of the past.*

*These examples are mine.

Comment: Your clarification was really helpful to get understand the answer to the problem. Thank you. Patriot.

Comment: @Dinu  You are very welcome!